# I see a button and I want it painted black

Tags: discussion, top-bar

The grayish buttons above looked nice with the the old gray bar above.
Now that we changed the design, can we change the buttons too ? Maybe I'm the only one with that opinion but it feels weird with those colors now. Ignore the question button I didn't want to change the CSS for the selected case but hey it could very well be inverted colors when selected like black on white.

Now :

> [image]

Could be :

> [image]

Comment: Well, action buttons (e.g. Post Your Question/Answer) are already black. :)

Comment: That bar isn't just for Meta

Comment: I'm tempted to vote up just for the witty, inventive title.

Comment: The bar isn't black.

Comment: @Yannis "I see a button and I want it painted #212121" doesn't exactly roll off the tongue.

Comment: I'm tempted to upvote for the question title as well, but won't because I don't want it mistaken for an agreement with your idea. :-)

Comment: Ah, the death of individuality. I can see it now. Every exchange will look exactly the same.

Answer (score 19):

Not black enough.

[image: Paint it ALL black]

Comment: What's this white text nonsense? Black on black or no deal.

Comment: technically, it's not *quite* white...

Comment: I actually like this. Reminds me of vim.

Comment: One you go black... well you know

Comment: If it were a wedding dress, it would be described as 'ivory' or 'pearl' or somesuch.

Comment: That cyan "meta" is _garish_. Take it away. Make it go away!

Comment: @Pops How dare you. I actually quite like it.

Comment: Not sure whether this was a serious answer or not, but +1 for "let's do that" (or at least make it an option - selectable colour scheme, mmmm...) (well, not exactly like that - "asked", for example, is very unreadable, and cyan - no ... just no).

Comment: [A 4-line user-script](http://pastebin.com/j0TuaLJk) got me [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XyS9S.png) - still deciding whether it's better or worse.